# How to use a custom hibernate.cfg.xml file path in Tapestry5

Tags: hibernate, tapestry

How can I change the name or path of the hibernate configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml` in a tapestry application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the class `AppModule` there are two methods that need to be changed or created:

1. `contributeApplicationDefaults`, to disable the default configuration
2. `contributeHibernateSessionSource` to provide your own.

```java
public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(
         MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration) {

    // Disable call to hibernate.configure() to call it manually 
    configuration.add(HibernateSymbols.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION, "false");
}
```

```java
public void contributeHibernateSessionSource(
        OrderedConfiguration<HibernateConfigurer> configurer) {

    configurer.add("hibernate-session-source", new HibernateConfigurer() {
        public void configure(org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration) {
            configuration.configure("my-hibernate.cfg.xml");
        }
    });
}
```

The id `hibernate-session-source` is arbitrary, anything seems to work. In [this discussion](http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Choosing-hibernate-configuration-td5081667.html) it's suggested to choose a unique one. Tested in Tapestry 5.3.6